# Eclipse RCP - How to rebuild project's index?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am developing an Eclipse Plugin which creates C projects.

How can I programmatically perform the action of:

**right click** on the project -> **Index** -> **rebuild**

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are developing a plugin for Eclipse CDT.

Without having more context I can't give you a complete answer. However, the index of an Eclipse CDT project can be rebuilt as follows:

```
CCorePlugin.getIndexManager().reindex(project); // reindex
                                                // note: project is an ICProject
CCorePlugin.getIndexManager().joinIndexer(IIndexManager.FOREVER, pm); // wait for the indexing job to complete.
```

In order to access the class `CCorePlugin` you need to add a dependency to the bundle `org.eclipse.cdt.core` to the MANIFEST.MF of your plugin.

Comment: Great! It worked! I had only the IProject, so I got the ICProject using: `CCorePlugin.getDefault().getCoreModel().getCModel().getCProject(iproject.getName())`

Comment: Great! Alternative way to get the `ICProject`: If you have an object of type `ICElement` (for instance an `ITranslationUnit`), you can obtain the `ICProject` that element belongs to via its `.getCProject()` method. Seems a bit cleaner to me than using the project name, but it's your choice :)

Answer (score 1):

In my eclipse, there is no "Index" in the context menu of a project.
Do you know the spy plugin?  You can gain information about active views and perhaps you are able to find the relavant information for you.

Read more on http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseCodeAccess/article.html#pluginspy

Comment: Thanks for the link, the spy plugin may be useful for me in the future.